# Set content before startActivity | Android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-activity

I want to create a transition for my app. For this I need at both ImageViews the same image. But I get the images from my server, so I have to set it at runtime. But there is my problem. How can I set the image for my second activity before I do startActivity with my Intent? Has someone a solution? Thanks!

Have a nice day

Comment: You can't set the image on a layout that isn't available. You could cache the image before starting the next activity, though

Comment: Do you mean there is an ImageView in your first Activity and second Activity that needs to show the same image and that image can be accessed from a url?

Comment: @s-hunter No, I get the image from a socket. And for the shared transition I have to set it in the second activity before I load it.

Comment: You have to start the activity, call the setContentView with the layout you have the ImageView, and then be able to set the image.

Comment: @s-hunter And this works for shared transition?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by shared transition...

Comment: @s-hunter this: http://www.androidauthority.com/using-shared-element-transitions-activities-fragments-631996/